# Django 1.11 python3 syntax error:EOL while scanning string literal in __init__ when migrating manage.py

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, syntax-error, django-migrations

I have been following Django installation tutorials and I have followed them exactly but when I have been trying to do:

```
python manage.py migrate
```

I get the following error:

```
  File "/.../settings/__init__.py", line 1
echo"from .base import *
                        ^
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
```

My `__init__.py` file is as follows, created as instructed by the Django documentation:

```
echo "from .base import * 

from .production import *

try:
    from .local import *
except:
    pass
" > __init__.py
```

I am using Python 3.7 and Django 1.11 in a virtual env.

I have tried using `"""` instead of `"` but it does not fix it.

Comment: There isn't anything in the documentation that says to put `echo` in the file or to surround it with quotes. You must be following some badly-explained third-party tutorial which wants you to create files from the command line. But don't do that.

Comment: Looks like this should be run from the shell to create `__init__.py`.

Comment: Could you possibly explain how I can correct this `__init__.py` file so that I do not get an error? When taking out the echo and the " marks, I get an invalid syntax error with the `>` symbol. What is the function of that `>` in the code here?

Comment: Your `__init__` file should only contain the text you currently have inside the quotation marks.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you created the `__init__.py` file in settings directory and paste the lines of codes in it. To get rid of the error, Just keep the lines inside the quotes. Delete `echo` and `"..."`. Matthias has already gave you the answer in the comment.

Answer (score 0):

the **init**.py file must contain only:

```python
from .base import * 

from .production import *

try:
    from .local import *
except:
    pass
```

then the `python manage.py migrate` command runs without error